# Issues with Image Links on Server

Tags: css, image

I seem to be having issues with my webpage once I load my files onto a server I am using. I suspect that the issue revolves around the local location of links vs. the location on the server but I am not sure how to alter the links so that they will work once on the server. Below is my CSS that I am using to display my background image which displays fine locally

```css
#topContainer {
    background-image:url("images/background.jpg");
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have double checked spelling and capital letter sensitivity but no luck. The image (background.jpg) exists in a subfolder labeled "images" 
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: try going directly to the image in your browser to make sure it is there and there were no permission issues on the images folder - is this css style in a css file inside a css folder?  if so, is the images folder in that css folder or outside of it?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by going directly to the image in my browser, when I open the file from fireFTP  it opens the default image viewer on my computer. The css style is actually in the same file as my html and javascript/Jquery. The parent folder contains the index.html file as well as the subfolder for the image labeled "images". the image is located in that subfolder. Hopefully this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change link from

```
background-image:url("/images/background.jpg");
```

If it help good but if not give us more information...

Comment: I tried this but no luck. Perhaps it something I am doing when transferring the files from my local machine to the server via FireFTP? I have tried transferring the parent folder as well as trying just the index.html file with the image subfolder with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

if your css is per se in this folder: project/css/style.css
and you're trying to call an image in another folder say project/images/image.jpg

then the code you should be using is

```html
background-image:url("../images/background.jpg");
```

Comment: I copied your code given that is the structure I am using, but it did not work. I wonder if there is anything else I need to know regarding the transferring to the server? I would think as long as I keep the same folder hierarchy I shouldn't need to change the image url? Idk if the link online will tell you anything 

file:///C:/Users/Kurt/AppData/Local/Temp/6-index.html

Comment: I pasted the incorrect link as I am sure that is obvious by now, posted below should work
http://217.199.187.63/m4m.com/